# Collaborative remote music recording

Tags: recording

Is there a network of musicians who can record musical phrases/tracks for other musicians?

I an an amateur musician, I write and record songs (voice, guitar, and virtual instruments such as keyboards, drums, etc.). What would be really cool is to replace some virtual instruments with real ones. For instance in one of my recent tunes there is a musical phrase in chorus that would sound really good if played by brass instruments (instead of a synthesizer). I don't know anybody who plays brass instruments. But surely there are people on the globe that can play and are willing to record something for other people (and get something recorded for them if they need).

The process can be something like this:

- Provide mp3 track with the draft of the tune (with the instrument to be recorded played using a virtual instrument).
- Provide mp3 track without the melody.
- Provide mp3 track of just the melody.
- Receive recorded track.
- Receive mp3 of recorded track merged with the original mp3 track without the melody.

So i thought is there an existing internet community of musicians who record and exchange music recording for production of their own music?

Comment: This is a really cool idea, and one in which I would definitely participate in if it existed.

Answer (score 2):

There have been several Web-based businesses that have built up around this idea over the years. Some are for amateurs and some are for professional session musicians. It's been awhile  since I have looked into this; if I come up with references I will post them here.

By the way, all of them will use MP3s only to provide "proof copies" for evaluation, but will provide full-bandwidth audio files in high-resolution formats such as FLAC, AIFF or WAV for actual recording and mixing.

Answer (score 2):

I think You may be interested in

http://www.indabamusic.com/

This is very active community. And i think that You find musicians within amator and better range.

They also sport some contest where You can hook up with pro's
They also have online DAW but i disliked it.

I think it's worth Your attention. It has free Basic subscription plan - so You can see around if You find there what You looking for.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kompoz.com seems to work pretty well, linking musicians from all over the world.